# How to generate multiple rows from single row where it contains 2 columns with numeric values to be looped in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this data

| Name | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andy | 2023-06 | 2023-09 |

Can I loop depending on the different between startDate and endDate, so that my result looks like this

| Name | joinDate |
| --- | --- |
| Andy | 2023-06 |
| Andy | 2023-07 |
| Andy | 2023-08 |
| Andy | 2023-09 |

So far I could not find solution in google or maybe my search keyword is incorrect. This is my first time asking in stackoverflow, let me know if I have anything wrong in my question. Thank you

Comment: Something like `select a.name, joinDate from table a cross join (select generate_series(startDate, endDate, interval '1 day') joinDate from table b where b.name = a.name) x`